# How can GWT know if it's first time to receive non-empty JSON data from back end?

Tags: java, gwt, dom-events

As the title said, when users have a totally fresh installed software, they may need to wait 3-5 minutes to make database run in the back end to get data in GUI. So, during the loading time, I just show "Please wait....".

In my GWT code, I use my own Timer class to call back end code every 2 seconds to get back end result through JSON. My question is, How can GWT code know it's first time to receive non-empty JSON data from back end database? Because I want to refresh the page immediately when the JSON object is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RequestBuilder, below is a simple example of displaying a waiting message when JSON request is sent and hiding it when response is received.

```
import com.google.gwt.http.client.Request;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.Request;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestCallback;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.Response;

RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, jsonServiceUrl);
requestBuilder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

RequestCallback jsonCallback = new RequestCallback () {
  @Override
  public final void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
     hideWaitingMessage();
     handleJsonResponse(request, response);
  }
  @Override
  void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
     hideWaitingMessage();
     handleError(response, exception);
  }
};

String requestData = null;
displayWaitingMessage();
Request request = requestBuilder.sendRequest(requestData, jsonCallback);
```